# Embed YouTube with WKWebView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, youtube, wkwebview

I am very new to MacOS Objective-C Coding. I know there are a lot of solutions for iOS on displaying a YouTube video, but I am attempting with MacOS and Objective C.

So far, I am using WKWebView to display a url. This work fine, except I more wanted to display a youtube video full screen in the window (and just the video, not the whole youtube webpage along with the video).

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.webNSView.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t168mpf0SxU"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.webNSView addSubview:webView];
```

My solution was to use embed instead of a direct url.

```
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/t168mpf0SxU"];
```

However, I resize the window the video doesn't resize the webview embed with the window. Is there a piece of code I'm missing for that?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to first set Auto Resize Mask Constraints:

```
[webView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Then to add layout constraints:

```
[self.webNSView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[webView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(webView)]];
    
[self.webNSView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[webView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(webView)]];
```

This seems to resize the WKWebView inside a NSView